# Couple that have ordered the maximum of common products - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trouble selecting the couple of customers that have ordered the maximum of common products.

Example :

- Customer1 ordered products : a, b, c, z
- Customer2 ordered products : a, c, d, g
- Customer1 ordered products : g, h, z

Expected result : Customer1 | Customer2 | 2 (Number of common products ordered)

What I tried :

```
SELECT c.pid, c.cid, d.cid, count(c.pid)
FROM orders c JOIN orders d join 
(SELECT a.cid, b.cid FROM customers a JOIN customers b ON b.cname != a.cname AND b.cname > a.cname) as subq
ON c.cid = a.cid and d.cid = b.cid
AND c.pid = d.pid group by c.pid;
```

This returns every couple of names :

```
select a.cname client_1, b.cname client_2
from customers a join customers b on b.cname != a.cname and b.cname > a.cname;
```

How can I get the max of common pids for a couple of cids ?

Tables :

```
customers (cid, cname, residence)
orders (pid, cid, odate, quantity)
products (pid, pname, price, origin)
```

Comment: Please, use formatted text not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Sorry, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

Might not work in every RDBMS. Which one are you using?

```
select o1.cid, o2.cid, o1.pid, o1.cnt, o2.cnt
from (
 select cid, pid, count(*) as cnt
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid, pid ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rn
 from order
 group by cid, pid
) as o1
join (
 select cid, pid, count(*) as cnt
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid, pid ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rn
 from order
 group by cid, pid
) as o2
on o1.cid <> o2.cid
and o1.pid = o2.pid

where o1.rn = 1
 and o2.rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm using Mysql, it says that there is a missing parenthesis on the over clause but i don't see anything missing...

Comment: Yeah, I think MySQL will support window function only starting next version. Than you will have to filter every sub-query like `where exists (select cid, max(cnt) m_cnt from (select cid, pid, count(*) as cnt from order group by cid, pid) as a) group by cid having max(cnt) = outer_query.cnt)`